# issue executing unix commands using system() in c

Tags: c, unix

I'm currently trying to write a program to accept user input to and execute commands in a unix system, the code compiles but when I run it I get a segmentation fault. I think it might be related to the input data type for the system() function but I can't seem to figure it out

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char argument[1024];
main() {
      fgets(argument, 1024, stdin);
      strtok (argument, "\n");
      char *command = strcat("cd ", argument);
      int response = system(command);
      if(response == -1)
      {
      printf("error executing command");
      }
}
```

I apologise if this seems trivial I don't have much experience with c

Comment: You are trying to concatenate onto a string literal.  A better approach might be to use `sprintf` to build your command string.

Comment: `man strcat`: `strcat(dest, src)`. first argument is a destination, and it should be large enough. you pass a string literal to the function. the length of that literal is `4` bytes, therefore it is overflow.

Comment: like this?
sprintf(command, "cd %s", argument);

Answer (score -1):

You are programming in C in an Unix system.

The language C was written just to write Unix itself. `system()` was written in C, Unix, Windows, Linux, Android, MacOS, Python, java, everything was written in C at first and still is at the most part.
And you have many `shells` in Unix and derivatives that just run commands as the user types them.
So to use `system()` to run a command does not add much. Just another level of indirection, an a big security hole, since your program can be used to do unexpected things by not so good people. Using YOUR program.

#### An alternative

This is the output of the program below

```
Current directory is: /home/testing/projects/tcursor
directory changed to '/tmp'
Enter name of directory to create: thing
'/tmp/thing' created
Now changing to newly created folder
Current directory is: '/tmp/thing'
```

The program just

- `cwd` to `/tmp`
- prompt for the name a folder to create
- creates the folder
- `cd` to it
- shows current dir
- returning 1,2,3,4 in case of error, 0 in case of success

So you can see some C code to `cd`, `pwd` and `mkdir`

```
int main(void)
{
    char        asw[30];
    char        buffer[1024];
    char*       p = buffer;
    const char* temp = "/tmp";

    p = getcwd(p,1024);
    printf("Current directory is: %s\n",p);
    int n = chdir(temp);
    if ( n != 0 ) return(1);
    printf("directory changed to '%s'\n", temp);
    printf("Enter name of directory to create: ");
    fgets(asw,30,stdin);
    asw[strlen(asw)-1] = 0;
    n = mkdir(asw, 0777 );
    if ( n != 0 ) return(2);
    printf("'%s' created\n", buffer);
    printf("Now changing to newly created folder\n");
    sprintf(buffer,"%s/%s", temp, asw);
    n = chdir(buffer);
    if ( n != 0 ) return(4);
    p = getcwd(p,1024);
    printf("Current directory is: '%s'\n",p);
    return 0;
```

Do not use `system()`